# Allow users to copy and paste code into their own website

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I've developed a web application in PHP and MySQL. One part of the system I've been putting on hold for a while now, is allowing my users to create a simple form inside my application, and once they're done, copy and paste some code which I generate into their existing remote websites (IE: Contact Form) where this form should appear.

When visitors to their site enter their data into that "contact form" or whatever they've created, it should save the info into my application database where the users will be able to access it. It must be unobtrusive.

Is there anyone who can give me a good starting point on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a little confused on what youre asking. Are you asking if there is a way to automatically copy the generated form to the clipboard, or how you set the form up to allow it to post data back to your own server?

If its the former, Bradley above pretty much explained it. If its the latter, then there are a couple of ways that you can go about doing it.

If you want it to submit the form without actually redirecting back to your own site, then you need to submit the form via AJAX (read [XMLHttpRequest](http://dochub.io/#dom/xmlhttprequest), or the $.ajax() function if youre using jQuery). The only problem here is that it violates the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) since youd be submitting from a different domain. To fix this, you need to setup your webserver to [allow cross domain requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) so that it'll actually work.

Comment: This is more in the right direction i would say. I will read into the cross domain requests a bit. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot access the clipboard to save (copy) text to memory. A general way around this is to use an invisible flash movie and place it over an input button so that 'clicking' the button triggers the flash script, which *can* utilize the clipboard.

I've used ZeroClipBoard in the past to do this, and I believe some of the syntax highlighting plugins out there use it as well.

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: Thanks Bradley, it sure is useful. But what i am looking for is how to actually show my applications form on a remote website and get that info back. An example of what i need is similar to GetSatisfaction.com/ There, you can paste javascript from their website into your own website and a form will appear which is generated by them, and results are stored with them. Maybe this will help explain what i need to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. What you need to do is create a javascript and save it as its own file (filename.js), and then generate a link to that script directly for them to paste on their own site.
    <script src="http://yoursite.com/path/to/their/custom/script.js></script>

Then use that script to build their form by creating dom elements. Alternatively, you can actually link to a PHP file but change the header and content-type to make the browser think you are writing a JS file, so that you can access your database and get their data.

Comment: Will i be able to load the php form via ajax from their site if i had them paste the loose standing js file path to their website?